# Collecting data which wasn't predicted when the system was designed

Tags: database, cron, software-design, database-administration

How do you go about collecting and storing data which was not part of the initial database and software design? For example, if you've come up with a pointing system, you have to collect the points for every user which has already been registered. For new users, that would be easy, because the changes of the business logic will reflect the pointing system ... but the old ones?

In general, how does one deal with data, which should have been there from the beginning, but wasn't? Writing manual queries to collect the missing pieces? Using crons?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are asking for something that is by definition not possible, I think.

> deal with data hich should have been there from the beginning, but wasn't?

Because if you **are able to deduce the number of points from the existing data** in the database. If that were possible, there is **obviously no missing data**.... Storing the points separately would make it redundant (still a fine option in case you need that for performance).

For example: stackoverflow rewards number of consecutive visits. Let's say they did not do that from the start. If they were logging date-of-visit already, you can recalc the points. So no missing data.

So if that is not possible, you need another solution: either get data from other sources (parse a webserver log) or get the business to draft some extra business rules for the determination of the default values for the existing users (difficult in this particular example).

> Writing manual queries to collect the missing pieces? Using crons?

I would populate that in a conversion script or even in a special conversion application if very complex.